# Fix order of function execution in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a registration process in which I have divided all the registration process in small methods. Now I want to restrict that methods can be invoked in a certain order So that they can log details in DB so that they get details from previous inserted data and can make new insert for next set of data. For Example:

Address - First to go in DB.
Contact - Second also contains Reference to Address.
User - Last and contains reference to Contact.

I have Invoked the methods in required order, but In future if any other programmer comes and he changes order so things should not break and some error should be generated.

Is this possible? Other approaches or suggestions are also welcomed.

Comment: don't make those methods public, if you don't want outsiders using them.

Comment: They are not public, they are private. I want to prevent invoke order modifications.

Comment: if they're private, then they can't be invoked by external code, so what's the problem?

Comment: Do you think, the code you write will not changed by any developer later in future? If yes then they can also modify the invoke order that you have written. So I want any one who modify my code and if they change the order of methods execution so he get notified that it need to be maintain that way. and if he want to change the order then he need to understand the process and change the complete process. This way I want to be assured that reg process is going the way its defined. Is it this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about PHP, but generally speaking, you could create a single public function (LogIn for instance) that call the methods in the desired order and modify you previous method not to be public. That way you can only access them from LogIn function. Hope this helps you

Comment: As I have already described in question that I have already created the functions and invoked in desired order and they are private. but the concern is Some one can change the order by editing the code So I want to make sure that If order get changed there should be some warning or errors and its get notified that Invoking order should be maintained.

Comment: I don't think that makes any sense. If a new programer came and have access to your code, he could simple delete your functions, creates new ones, in other words alter completly your code. So its imposible to "prevent" to call the functions in wrong order. You have only one option. Find a way to encapsulate your code, and only give access to public methods. That way you can ensure execution order but the new programer won't have access to the code that describes the functions. In PHP that's not posible (as long as i know).You can write a c# DLL to encapsulate your code or create a WEB service

Comment: @AshishAwasthi: So you want to prevent a new programmer from incorrectly using your methods?  This is what documentation and comments are for.

Comment: @RocketHazmat documentation and comments are there but I want good  control on the flow. Thats why I want to make rules on the execution of methods, which need to follow or change the flow completely, instead of executing wrong flow.

Comment: As mention above, you can't do that. Not with PHP (as long as I know) because the code is open.